# Why do I keep texting myself voice mail transcripts?

Tags: htc-sense, htc-evo-3d, sprint

I am having an issue trying to assess why I am texting transcripts to myself of the voice mails people leave me.

The Problem: I have an HTC EVO 3D on Sprint, and whenever someone leaves a message I get a notification in my gmail inbox of the transcript via Google Voice (ding #1). Shortly thereafter, I then get a notification (ding #2), and then 2-3 text messages (dings #4-5) on the HTC Sense texting app widget, from myself via my carrier's phone number (that is, the non-Google number). As you can imagine, it is incredibly irritating.

Background: Looking into the Voicemail settings on the phone, and the Visual Voicemail settings, I don't have anything enabled to cause this behavior (I am not signed up for the latter service, and the trial hasn't even been configured). Google Voice isn't to blame for these text messages; they are set up to only push to gmail. The texting app itself is of no use in terms of finding out where it is getting these notifications from; it says it's from my carrier's number, but nothing else.

Please let me know any suggestions you have to:
 - diagnose the source of the 2-3 text messages; they are the truly aggravating "feature" of this problem. I am not sure if this is caused at the carrier, hardware, or software level.
 - turn off the notification (sound) for the 2-3 text messages, or to disable the texts from myself entirely. As you might expect, I still want to receive notifications for other text messages, so muting the app wholesale is not an option. I am okay with ditching the HTC app, so if there is one (hopefully with a workspace display) that can selectively mute users (e.g. myself) that might be an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Voice is responsible for these; they are sent by default. See in the settings:

[image: Google Voice setting]

You can uncheck this box and Google Voice will refrain from sending you SMS transcripts of your voicemails from then on. 
Also **note**, unchecking the box above titled `Email the message to:` only prevents email transcripts, not SMS ones.